# Android: How to save sharedPreferences in activity A and access it in activity B

Tags: java, android, android-sharedpreferences

I saw this question has been asked before, however none of the answers provided worked for me.

So, I have two activities: A and B. The user inserts some data in A and I want to be able to access to them from B (and more activities in the future). I'm trying to do that using shared preferences. Right now it seems that my code is able to correctly save the data in activity A however I am not able to access to the same sharedPreference from activity B as the object (in activity B) is empty. It looks like it creates another object with the same name.

I'm very new to android and java so I know it's probably just me not understanding how this class works, what am I doing wrong?

Activity A

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences("PREF_PERSONAL_DATA",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

editor.putInt(getString(R.string.n),n);
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.hi), hi);
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.wa), wa);
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.he), he);
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.we), we);
editor.putInt(BlocksNumStr, BlocksNum);
editor.commit();
```

Activity B

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = this.getSharedPreferences("PREF_PERSONAL_DATA", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

String Weight = sharedPref.getString("we", null);
int W = sharedPref.getInt("weight", 0);

TextView ShowWeight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.attempt);
ShowWeight.setText(Weight);
TextView ShowW = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.attemptW);
ShowW.setText(W);
```

Comment: Have you tried using Strings as keys instead of getString(R.string.we) to see if that's your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`A` is storing an `int` value, but `B` is attempting to retrieve it as a `String` -- which should cause [SharedPreferences.getString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to throw a `ClassCastException`. I surmise that your second code snippet is surrounded by a try/catch that is catching this exception.

You have to retrieve an `int` using [SharedPreferences.getInt()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getInt(java.lang.String,%20int)).

Answer (score 1):

Android comes with 3 types of access to the `SharedPreferences`:

1. `Activity.getPreferences()` - accesses Activity-specific preferences. This will be valid only for ActivityA or ActivityB in your case.
2. `Activity.getSharedPreferences()` or `Context.getSharedPreferences` when not in Activity - accesses Application-level preferences. Those preferences are visible everywhere within your application.

   3. `PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()` - accesses global shared preferences visible for every application installed on Android.

From the example you've posted everything seems to be correct because you use `getSharedPreferences()`. The things I would check would be:

1. to ensure whether same `String` keys from resources are used to retrieve the preferences.
2. to check whether the `commit()` method does not break writing batch of preferences. Personally, I experienced some issues with preferences not being stored when using `commit()` method. From Android Honeycomb there is an `apply()` method. The difference between `commit()` and `apply()` is that the `commit()` saves preferences on whatever thread you are on whereas `apply()` works asynchronously. If you're not dependent on pre-Honeycomb versions consider using `apply()`.

Answer (score 0):

The safest way to make sure that you are using the same shared preferences instance is to call the

```
getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context context)
```

First add these to your two Activties A and B

private SharedPreference mSharedPreference;
private SharedPreference.Editor mEditor;

initiate them in onCreate like that:

```
mSharedPreference = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
mEditor = mSharedPreference.edit();
```

to save to the sharedPreference do that:

```
mEditor.put("KEY",variableToSave);
mEditor.apply();
```

to read (activity B):
//reading a previously saved string (for example...)

```
String readVariable = mSharedPreferences.getString("KEY","DEAULT_VALUE");
```

Using the default shared preference will give you access to the files in your whole app. So you will have access to the variables that you save using the editor everywhere (in activity A or B);

Answer (score 0):

activity A  :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref =     getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("PREF_PERSONAL_DATA",getBaseContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

editor.putInt(getString(R.string.n),n);
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.hi), hi);
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.wa), wa);
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.he), he);
editor.putInt(getString(R.string.we), we);
editor.putInt(BlocksNumStr, BlocksNum);
editor.commit();
```

activity B :

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("PREF_PERSONAL_DATA", getBaseContext().MODE_PRIVATE);

String Weight = sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.wa), null);
int W = sharedPref.getInt("weight", 0);

TextView ShowWeight = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.attempt);
ShowWeight.setText(Weight);
TextView ShowW = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.attemptW);
ShowW.setText(W);
```